# How can I restore a deleted forked repository from a local clone?

Tags: git, github, fork, push

Now after deleting the forked repo, if i try to push from my command line it shows that repository does not exist. But I can still pull changes from original repo through upstream remote.

Comment: Just fork it again. Assuming any differences from the original still exist in your local repository, a push will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

ahh! I can simply fork back the repo again and get all my work!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).